# How do I make dynamically created inputs in R/Shiny flow like normal inputs in flowLayout?

Tags: r, dynamic, input, shiny

I have a mix of dynamically created inputs and normally defined inputs.  The dynamically created inputs behave like a large vertically stacked block that the other inputs flow around.  How do I make them all flow together?

This reproduces the issue:

```
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      flowLayout(
        uiOutput('input_fields'),
        textInput('fielda','Field A',''),
        textInput('fieldb','Field B',''),
        textInput('fieldc','Field C',''),
        textInput('fieldd','Field D','')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$input_fields <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:4, function(i) {
        textInput(paste0('field',i), paste('Field',i),'')
      })
    })
  }
)
```

Current layout:

[image]

Desired layout:

[image]

Edit:  Ignore the Field A,B,C,D widgets.  They are just for showing how other items wrap but the uiOutput ones act as one block.  Assume all inputs are dynamic.

I think I'm to use this code instead.  It moves the renderUI inside the lapply to create multiple generic outputs (varies at runtime, up to 10) which I can reference with equally generic uiOutput statements.  It doesn't even warn about the 5 outputs that don't exist.  Not perfect but it'll do. Probably need to add in an observeEvent as I don't think it will be reactive on its own.

```
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      wellPanel(
        flowLayout(
          uiOutput('field1'),
          uiOutput('field2'),
          uiOutput('field3'),
          uiOutput('field4'),
          uiOutput('field5'),
          uiOutput('field6'),
          uiOutput('field7'),
          uiOutput('field8'),
          uiOutput('field9'),
          uiOutput('field10')
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      output[[paste0('field',i)]] <- renderUI({
        textInput(paste0('field',i), paste('Field',i),'')
      })
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All four dynamic generated widgets are treated as one object because they are contained in a list. Therefore it is quite difficult to position them. 
The easiest solution I can think of is to use `insertUI` function from the newest shiny version which can be installed using `devtools` package:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/shiny")
```

([Here](http://shiny.rstudio-staging.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) you can read/learn more about `insertUI` and `removeUI`)

We have to tell `insertUI` where it should add new widgets to the user interface, and we do it by specifying the parameter `selector` (it has to be a string that is accepted by jQuery selector) and the parameter `where` (there are four choices which which specify how widgets should go relative to the selector)

So if we want to add a new widget under `Field 1` we have to set `selector = "#fielda"` (We use `#` selector since we are referring to the ID). Similarly, we add another widget under `Field 2` by setting `selector = "#fieldb"` and so on. Following your naming convention we can generalize it to:

```
selector = paste0('#field', letters[i])
```

In all cases we also set `where = "afterEnd`. It will position new widgets below reference widgets. (There is no space to position them above reference widgets)

Now we can wrap `insertUI` into a `for-loop`

```
for (i in 1:4) { 
      insertUI(
        selector = paste0('#field', letters[i]), 
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = textInput(paste0('field',i), paste('Field',i),'')
      )
    }
```

Note that we don't need to add any `uiOutput` on the client side.

The other solution would be to render whole `dashboardBody` on the server side creating dynamically distinct `uiOutput`s...which wouldn't be pleasant.

---

[image]

When we take a look at the picture we can see that I did it the other way around - capital letters in names in the first row and numbers in names in the second row. It shouldn't be a big deal I hope :)

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      flowLayout(
        textInput('fielda','Field A',''),
        textInput('fieldb','Field B',''),
        textInput('fieldc','Field C',''),
        textInput('fieldd','Field D','')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    for (i in 1:4) { 
      insertUI(
        selector = paste0('#field', letters[i]), 
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = textInput(paste0('field',i), paste('Field',i),'')
      )
    }
  }
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If there are no reference widgets then you can also dynamically define `flowLayout` on the server side using non-standard evaluation.

Say, you want to generate three `textInput` widgets. You would normally do this by typing

```
flowLayout(
  textInput('fielda', 'Field A'),
  textInput('fieldb', 'Field B'),   
  textInput('fieldc', 'Field C')
)
```

on the client side. You can do the same thing by pasting strings with `paste0` function on the server side,

```
        i = 1:3
        UI <- paste0("flowLayout(",
                paste0("textInput(", 
                       "'field", letters[i], "', ",
                       paste0("'Field ", LETTERS[i], "'"), 
                       ")",
                       collapse = ", "),
              ")")
```

saving it in a variable, say, `UI`, then parsing string and finally evaluating it.

```
eval(parse(text = UI))
```

---

In the example below you have 15 dynamically generated widgets

[image]

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      wellPanel(
      uiOutput("ui1")
    )
   )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

      output[["ui1"]] <- renderUI({
        i = 1:15
        UI <- paste0("flowLayout(",
                paste0("textInput(", 
                       "'field", letters[i], "', ",
                       paste0("'Field ", LETTERS[i], "'"), 
                       ")",
                       collapse = ", "),
              ")")
        # print(UI)
        eval(parse(text = UI))
      })

  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This gives me one more avenue to pursue but was not exactly what I was looking for.   This method ties a dynamic UI widget to a normal widget and you can only insert the widget below an existing widget; so A-1, B-2, C-3, D-4 flow in pairs.  What if the dynamic part generates 20 UI widgets and there are no reference widgets, ie only dynamic widgets exist?  My example was probably misleading; it was meant to show that other items flow around the dynamic widgets as a block, as you mention.  I will edit my post to be more clear but I suspect I will have to create indiv inputs.

Comment: I updated my answer but it is only meant to show another possibility where you paste everything you want to have in the flowLayout :) It can be generalized, however, defining variables with strings to be pasted and then using 100x paste0 would be  just pain :)

Comment: Thank you for the followup and interesting solution.  I may be able to work with that.