# How to make dynamically generated shiny UI elements 'flow'

Tags: r, shiny, flowlayout

I am trying to  dynamically generate shinyn UI elements placed horizontally one after another (left to right). The `flowlayout` seems perfect for it, however when the elements are dynamically generated using lapply it is being treated as a single element, and get placed vertically one below another.

Example code below

```
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- flowLayout(
    lapply(1:4,function(i){
      selectInput(paste0("input_1",i),"input", choices=1:5)
    })
  )
  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

However when  not generated dynamically they are placed horizontally(left to right) one after an other, which is what I am looking for. Any pointers as to how this can be fixed?

EDIT: I found this nice response to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39069479/1012249), but Im wondering if a non `'eval-parse'` solution possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  do.call(flowLayout,
          lapply(1:4, function(i){
            selectInput(paste0("input_1",i), "input", choices=1:5)
          })
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

Comment: While this works, could you help me out by explaining why one works and the other doesnt?