# Is it possible to arrange Shiny app cards in a masonry grid?

Tags: r, layout, shiny, masonry

I am currently trying to create a "wall" of cards from a dataframe for a hobby Shiny app. Adapting from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741986/create-dynamic-number-of-card-elements-in-shiny-flowlayout), here is a minimal complete example of my code:

```
library(shiny)

df <- read.csv("https://github.com/intelligence-refinery/shiny_app/raw/master/flyer.csv")

card <- function(img, item, store) {
    HTML(
        paste0(
            '<div class="card">
              <div class="container">
              <h4><b>', item, '</b></h4>
              </div>
              <img src="', img, '" style="width:100%">
              <div class="container">
              <h5><i>', store, '</i></h5>
              </div>
              </div>'
        )
    )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style('.card {
                         width: 250px;
                       clear: both;
                       /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
                       box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                       transition: 0.3s;
                       }
                       /* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
                       .card:hover {
                       box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                       }
                       /* Add some padding inside the card container */
                       .container {
                       width: 250px;
                       padding: 2px 16px;
                       }')),
    uiOutput("cards")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$cards <- renderUI({
        # First make the cards
        args <-
            lapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(x)
                card(df[x, "clean_image_url"],
                     store = df[x, "store_name"],
                     item = df[x, "name"]))

        # Make sure to add other arguments to the list:
        args$cellArgs <- list(style = "
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 5px;
            ")

        # basically the same as flowLayout(cards[[1]], cards[[2]],...)
        do.call(shiny::flowLayout, args)

    })
}


# Preview the UI in the console
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this results in unsightly gaps between the cards, as they are different size:

[image: gaps between cards]

A [**masonry grid layout**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns) would be ideal in this situation:

[image: masonry grid example]

Since I'm very new to web work of any kind, I'm unsure as to how to apply the pure CSS/Javascript solutions to my Shiny app. I have tried to adapt the example from the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/), but when I pasted the HTML and CSS to CodePen, I am not getting a complete example...

The closest that I have found to an example of creating a masonry grid in a Shiny app is the (quite complex) [conference Twitter dashboard](https://apps.garrickadenbuie.com/rstudioconf-2019/). I found the relevant section in the [code](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tweet-conf-dash/blob/master/ui.R#L217). However, as I am quite new to any web work, I can't adapt it to my own code.

Is there a way to create a masonry layout for a panel of cards generated this way? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can divide your images into some meaninful number of columns, then before laying out your horizontal layout, you can wrap sets of images in `column`. Then arrange the columns with `fluidRow`.

Here is an example using just the first 20 rows from your data. Pasting the `server` only. The other change was to add `df <- df[1:20,]` after loading the data:

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$cards <- renderUI({
        # First make the cards
        args <-
            lapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(x)
                card(df[x, "clean_image_url"],
                     store = df[x, "store_name"],
                     item = df[x, "name"]))

        # Make sure to add other arguments to the list:
        args$cellArgs <- list(style = "
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 5px;
            ")

        # make five columns with four images each
        cols <-
          lapply(seq(4, dim(df)[1], 4), function(x) {
              column(width = 2, verticalLayout(args[(x - 3):x], fluid = TRUE))
          })


        # then use fluidRow to arrange the columns 
        do.call(shiny::fluidRow, cols)

    })
}
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much teofil! It works like a charm! :)